# After upgrading to Android Studio 3.4 getting this error

Tags: android, compilation

I have a project which was made on Android Studio 3.3 and it was working fine without any issues but now when i have upgraded it to Android Studio 3.4 I am getting this compile error.

I have added that Java 1.8 version and all but non of that helped me.

Here is my Build.APP file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "applicationID"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 14
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.5.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.9.6'
    //    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.9.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.5.0'
    // Firebase Messages
    // Add the In-App Messaging depencency:
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.1.1'
    // Check that your Firebase dependency is up-to-date:
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is my Build.Project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here are the Error pictures that i am getting when i try to compile it.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFMUu.png)

[image: Error 2]

[image]

Comment: Change your minSdkVersion to 26

Answer (score 1):

I just disable the Instant Run from Preferences and now everything is fine

Comment: `InstantRun` is as broken as it can get unforunately. But I liked the idea of it

Comment: Instant Run never have worked for me, always have some issues while compiling projects. I am good without it nor i need that broken feature 

Comment: While its true that nobody "needs" it, it comes in handy if you have a very big app (around 300 MB) which takes about 3-5 Minutes to build/deploy vs 30 sec with InstantRun. Provided it is working for a sec :)